# Is it possible for the initialization of a STATIC local variable to be skipped by 'case' label?

Tags: c, static, initialization

I'm using Visual Studio and get an error C2360: **initialization of 'p' is skipped by 'case' label** while compiling the following code (simplified):

```
case 1:
static char*p[] = 
        {
            "000000000",
            "111111111",
            "222222222",
            "333333333",
            "444444444",
        };
...
break;

case 2: //  error C2360
....
```

As far as I know, a STATIC local variable is exactly the same as a global variable, except that it's only visible to the function in which it is declared. This means that the initialization of it has finished as early as the **main** function has not yet started to execute. Therefore, in my opinion, it's impossible for the initialization of the **'p'** to be skipped.

Am I right? Why did I receive that compilation error?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/61af7cx3(v=vs.100).aspx):

> "You cannot jump past a declaration with an initializer unless the
>   declaration is enclosed in a block."

So the resolution to the problem is:

```
case 1:
    {
       static char*p[] = 
       {
           "000000000",
           "111111111",
           "222222222",
           "333333333",
           "444444444",
       };

       // ... code that uses p
    }
    break;
```

Comment: I know bracketing the code can suppress the error, and I can understand why doing so works for a AUTO local variable. I just can't understand why that error should occur for a STATIC local variable. Thanks anyway.